# Angular 2 filter errors made together

Tags: angular, typescript

I am applying Angular hotel. I am trying to do hotel name search and hotel zone search filters. When I search for a hotel name, the code works correctly, but when I add a region search, the code is broken and the two searches for the region together. How can I fix?

.html

```
<form class="example-form">
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Which Hotel?" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let hotel of filteredOptions | async" [value]="hotel">
           {{hotel.hotelName}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>

<<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Which Region?" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let hotel of filteredOptions | async" [value]="hotel">
            {{hotel.regionName}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

.ts

```
myControl = new FormControl();
filteredOptions: Observable<Hotel[]>;

this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
        .pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(value => this._filter(value))
        );

    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
        .pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(value => this._filter2(value))
       );

private _filter(value: string): Hotel[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.hotels.filter(option => option.hotelName.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
}

private _filter2(value: string): Hotel[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.hotels.filter(option => option.regionName.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));

}
```

Comment: You are using the same formControl `myControl` for both hotel and regions input field. Use 2 different `FormControl` or group them together using `FormGroup`.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

You have a list of `Hotel` objects with the properties `hotelName` and `regionName`.

You want to add an input for each property with an autocomplete to your HTML.

### Your implementation

The core of the problem with your implementation is that you are using the same form control, filter, and autocomplete definitions for both sets of controls.

### The solution

Declare a form control for each input

```js
private formControls: {
  name: FormControl;
  region: FormControl
};

ngOnInit() {
  this.formControls = {
    name: this.formBuilder.control(''),
    region: this.formBuilder.control('')
  };

  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: this.formControls.name,
    region: this.formControls.region
  });

  // ...
}
```

Now build your observables to listen for form value changes

```js
filteredHotels: Observable<string[]>;
filteredRegions: Observable<string[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  // ...

  this.filteredHotels = this.formControls.name.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this.filterHotels(value))
    );

  this.filteredRegions = this.formControls.region.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this.filterRegions(value))
    );
}

private filterHotels(value: string): string[] {
  const name = value.toLowerCase();

  return this.hotels
    .map(x => x.hotelName)
    .filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(name));
}

private filterRegions(value: string): string[] {
  const region = value.toLowerCase();

  return this.regions
    .filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(region));
}
```

The region filter is using a distinct list of regions that have been derived from the hotels:

```js
private regions: string[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.regions = this.hotels.reduce((arr: string[], current) => {
    if (!arr.includes(current.regionName)) {
      arr.push(current.regionName);
    }
    return arr;
  }, []);
}
```

In your HTML, bind each input to the dedicated form control, and you need to declare unique versions of `#auto="matAutocomplete"`.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Which Hotel?" matInput 
    formControlName="name" [matAutocomplete]="name" />
    <mat-autocomplete #name="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let hotel of filteredHotels | async" [value]="hotel">
          {{hotel}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Which Region?" matInput formControlName="region" [matAutocomplete]="region" />
    <mat-autocomplete #region="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let region of filteredRegions | async" [value]="region">
        {{region}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmbvpt

Comment: @enesturan What do you mean "not working"? Do you mean in my demo or your implementation of it? Can you post a stackblitz

Comment: The demo worked, but it didn't work in my application. Sorry I could not install the application here because it is a database structure but if you want you can look here. 
Here it is https://github.com/enisturan/KodYazilim.HotelReservation

Comment: @enesturan So you're saying that the answer is correct, and there's something else wrong in your app?

Comment: Now it worked. Line 91. Thank you for your help. https://github.com/enisturan/KodYazilim.HotelReservation/commit/226e50570caf6f12043541ed364531e81e784c83